# Open Recordset with nested queries

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a recordset in Access VBA. I have written my SQL string in VBA as I am using Select Top with a variable. Currently I am getting run time error 3061 - too few parameters. expected 1

My SQL string is populating a form as a RecordSource so I know that the string is functional. My problem comes when I try to open that recordset in order to further manipulate the data.

I believe this error is due to the fact that my SQL string is referencing two other queries in the database. Is there a way to get around the parameters error?

Here is my code. Apologies if the formatting is incorrect

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim skip As String
Dim sqlstr As String

skip = "select [skip lot qty] from [Requirements] where [requirements].[part no] = eval('[forms]![main menu]![part no]')"


Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(skip)


Dim SLQ As Integer

SLQ = rs![skip lot qty]

Dim vendor As String
vendor = [Forms]![Main Menu]![Vendor No]

sqlstr = "SELECT TOP " & SLQ & " [Vendor Log].[ID],[Vendors Query].[Vendor Name], [Vendor Log].[Vendor No], [Vendor Log].[Date], [Vendors Query].[Last Qtr Rating], "

sqlstr = sqlstr & "[Vendor Log].[Part No] , [Requirements Query].[Skip Lot], [Requirements Query].[Plan No], [Vendor Log].[Inspection Req'd], [Vendor Log].[PO Number], "

sqlstr = sqlstr & "[Vendor Log].[Qty Received], [Vendor Log].[Sample Qty], [Vendor Log].[Accept Lot], [Vendor Log].[Comments], [Vendor Log].[Inspector Clock No], "

sqlstr = sqlstr & "[Vendor Log].[Counter], [Requirements Query].[Rev Date], [Requirements Query].[Rev Note], IIf([Accept Lot]=""R"",1,0) AS [R Counter], "

sqlstr = sqlstr & "IIf([Inspection Req'd]=""Yes"",1,0) AS [Yes Counter], IIf([Dim A]=""N/A"",""No"",""Yes"") AS [Dim Insp], IIf([Accept Lot] Is Null,1,0) AS"

sqlstr = sqlstr & " [Null Counter], [Requirements Query].[skip lot qty] FROM [Vendors Query] INNER JOIN ([Requirements Query] INNER JOIN [Vendor Log] ON "

sqlstr = sqlstr & " [Requirements Query].[Part No] = [Vendor Log].[Part No]) ON [Vendors Query].[Vendor No] = [Vendor Log].[Vendor No]"

sqlstr = sqlstr & " WHERE ((([Vendor Log].Date) > (Date - 1095)) And (([Vendor Log].[Vendor No]) = '" & vendor & "')) ORDER BY [Vendor Log].[ID] DESC;"

Debug.Print sqlstr
''setting the record source of the form to the string
Me.RecordSource = sqlstr

Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database


Set db = CurrentDb


Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(sqlstr) >>this is the error
```

Vendor Log is a table while Requirements Query and Vendors Query are select queries that reference tables using information from the previous form.

I would like to open this recordset in order to sum the different counters that are in the string.

I have pasted the sqlstr into a new query and it runs fine. I have double checked all the table names and ran both requirements query and vendors queries through the database with no problems.

Please help!

Edit: Output of Debug.Print:

```
SELECT TOP 4 [Vendor Log].[ID],[Vendors Query].[Vendor Name], [Vendor Log].[Vendor No], [Vendor Log].[Date], [Vendors Query].[Last Qtr Rating], [Vendor Log].[Part No] , [Requirements Query].[Skip Lot], [Requirements Query].[Plan No], [Vendor Log].[Inspection Req'd], [Vendor Log].[PO Number], [Vendor Log].[Qty Received], [Vendor Log].[Sample Qty], [Vendor Log].[Accept Lot], [Vendor Log].[Comments], [Vendor Log].[Inspector Clock No], [Vendor Log].[Counter], [Requirements Query].[Rev Date], [Requirements Query].[Rev Note], IIf([Accept Lot]="R",1,0) AS [R Counter], IIf([Inspection Req'd]="Yes",1,0) AS [Yes Counter], IIf([Dim A]="N/A","No","Yes") AS [Dim Insp], IIf([Accept Lot] Is Null,1,0) AS [Null Counter], [Requirements Query].[skip lot qty] FROM [Vendors Query] INNER JOIN ([Requirements Query] INNER JOIN [Vendor Log] ON  [Requirements Query].[Part No] = [Vendor Log].[Part No]) ON [Vendors Query].[Vendor No] = [Vendor Log].[Vendor No] WHERE ((([Vendor Log].Date) > (Date - 1095)) And (([Vendor Log].[Vendor No]) = 'PO1296')) ORDER BY [Vendor Log].[ID] DESC;
```

Edit 2:
Sorry these are long queries! This is the Requirements query. [Part numbers] is a table, [requirements] is a table

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW TOP 1 [Part Numbers].[Part No], [Part Numbers].Description, [Part Numbers].[Matl Type], [Part Numbers].Illustration, [Part Numbers].Obsolete, [Part Numbers].UOM, Requirements.[Skip Lot], Requirements.[Plan No], Requirements.Material, Requirements.[ID Reference], Requirements.Comment, Requirements.Functional, Requirements.Finish, Requirements.Cosmetic, Requirements.[Packaging - General], Requirements.[Individual Label/Tag], Requirements.[UPC Code], Requirements.[Qty per Pack], Requirements.[Pack Label], Requirements.[I2of5 Pack], Requirements.[Qty per Case], Requirements.[Case Label], Requirements.[I2of5 Case], Requirements.[Case Check Req'd?], Requirements.[Case Length (In)], [Case Length (In)]-([Case Length (In)]*0.15) AS [Case L Min], [Case Length (In)]+([Case Length (In)]*0.15) AS [Case L Max], Requirements.[Case Width (In)], [Case Width (In)]-([Case Width (In)]*0.15) AS [Case W Min], [Case Width (In)]+([Case Width (In)]*0.15) AS [Case W Max], Requirements.[Case Height (In)], [Case Height (In)]-([Case Height (In)]*0.15) AS [Case H Min], [Case Height (In)]+([Case Height (In)]*0.15) AS [Case H Max], Requirements.[Case Weight], [Case Weight]-([Case Weight]*0.15) AS [Case Wt Min], [Case Weight]+([Case Weight]*0.15) AS [Case Wt Max], Requirements.Certs, Requirements.[Dim A], Requirements.[A Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim B], Requirements.[B Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim C], Requirements.[C Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim D], Requirements.[D Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim E], Requirements.[E Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim F], Requirements.[F Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim G], Requirements.[G Tolerance], Requirements.[Dim H], Requirements.[H Tolerance], Requirements.[Other Dim], Requirements.[Other Tol], Requirements.[WLL (lbs)], Requirements.[WLL (kg)], Requirements.[BF Test Data], Requirements.[Breaking Force (lbs)], Requirements.[BF Test Req'd?], Requirements.[BF Sample], Requirements.Elongation, Requirements.Comments, Requirements.[Rev Date], Requirements.[Rev Note], IIf([Dim A]="N/A","No","Yes") AS [Dim Insp], Requirements.[Spec Ref], Requirements.[skip lot qty]
FROM [Part Numbers] INNER JOIN Requirements ON [Part Numbers].[Part No] = Requirements.[Part No]
WHERE ((([Part Numbers].[Part No])=[Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]))
ORDER BY Requirements.[Rev Date] DESC;
```

Vendors query: Vendors and Ratings are both tables

```
SELECT Vendors.[Vendor No], Vendors.[Vendor Name], Vendors.Obsolete, Vendors.[Last Qtr Rating], Ratings.[Last Rating Score]
FROM Ratings INNER JOIN Vendors ON Ratings.[Last Qtr Rating] = Vendors.[Last Qtr Rating]
WHERE (((Vendors.Obsolete)=No))
ORDER BY Vendors.[Vendor Name];
```

Comment: Are all of the referenced forms open when you run this code?

Comment: Yes there is only one form being referenced and it is open.

Comment: Debug.Print constructed SQL statement. Edit question to show this output. Form shows correct records after RecordSource is changed?

Comment: I added the Debug.Print output. I ran this through a query before I posted and it returns the correct information. My form populates successfully with this string set as the recordsource.

Comment: Also, can you provide the SQL for the other two queries please? If one of those queries contains parameters, you can't use Database.OpenRecordset, you will have to use QueryDef.OpenRecordset and set the parameters manually. This would explain why the query is working in other places.

Comment: I added the SQL for the other queries. Is the problem that I'm referencing a form in the requirements query? If so, how do I add the part no definition into that query in VBA?

Comment: Yes, that parameter is the issue. I'm trying a couple options and will let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you will do with `rs2` once you open it successfully.  But I wonder if this might suit: `Set rs2 = Me.RecordsetClone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is due to the fact that `Database.OpenRecordset` cannot be used with named queries that contain parameters. Your Requirements query contains a reference to a form field, which is a parameter and must be set explicitly using a QueryDef object.

This strange quirk is also why the query works in all other situations accept when you call it via `Database.OpenRecordset`.

**The simplest solution** would be to save the SQL in sqlstr as a named query, open it via a QueryDef object, set its parameters (vendor and [Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]) and then open a recordset by calling `QueryDef.OpenRecordset`.

Code would look similar to this:

```
    Dim qdf as QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("namedQuery") ' replace with name of new query

' optionally, use this RegExp to replace "SELECT TOP n" dynamically
' requires reference: Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'    Dim regex As New RegExp
'    regex.IgnoreCase = True
'    regex.Global = True
'    regex.Pattern = "(SELECT TOP )[0-9]+"
'    qdf.SQL = regex.Replace(qdf.SQL, "SELECT TOP " & rs![skip lot qty])

    qdf.Parameters("vendor") = [Forms]![Main Menu]![Vendor No]
    qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]") = [Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]

    Set rs2 = qdf.OpenRecordset
    qdf.Close
```

New named query would look like this (notice vendor parameter):

```
SELECT TOP 4 [Vendor Log].[ID],[Vendors Query].[Vendor Name], [Vendor Log].[Vendor No], [Vendor Log].[Date], [Vendors Query].[Last Qtr Rating], [Vendor Log].[Part No] , [Requirements Query].[Skip Lot], [Requirements Query].[Plan No], [Vendor Log].[Inspection Req'd], [Vendor Log].[PO Number], [Vendor Log].[Qty Received], [Vendor Log].[Sample Qty], [Vendor Log].[Accept Lot], [Vendor Log].[Comments], [Vendor Log].[Inspector Clock No], [Vendor Log].[Counter], [Requirements Query].[Rev Date], [Requirements Query].[Rev Note], IIf([Accept Lot]="R",1,0) AS [R Counter], IIf([Inspection Req'd]="Yes",1,0) AS [Yes Counter], IIf([Dim A]="N/A","No","Yes") AS [Dim Insp], IIf([Accept Lot] Is Null,1,0) AS [Null Counter], [Requirements Query].[skip lot qty] FROM [Vendors Query] INNER JOIN ([Requirements Query] INNER JOIN [Vendor Log] ON  [Requirements Query].[Part No] = [Vendor Log].[Part No]) ON [Vendors Query].[Vendor No] = [Vendor Log].[Vendor No] WHERE ((([Vendor Log].Date) > (Date - 1095)) And (([Vendor Log].[Vendor No]) = vendor)) ORDER BY [Vendor Log].[ID] DESC;
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by HansUp, TOP only accepts literals and won't accept a parameter. You can either statically specify TOP n in your query or drop TOP altogether if your table isn't very large (10,000+ records). Or you can use the Regular Expression I included in code above

Another excellent point by HansUp would remove the need for the RegExp. You could use the following code as well:

```
    Dim qdf as QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("") ' creates temporary querydef

    qdf.SQL = "SELECT TOP " & SLQ & "rest of sqlstr..."    

    qdf.Parameters("vendor") = [Forms]![Main Menu]![Vendor No]
    qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]") = [Forms]![Main Menu]![Part No]

    Set rs2 = qdf.OpenRecordset
    qdf.Close
```

Comment: Access SQL will not accept a parameter for `TOP` ... you must include a literal number in the statement text.

Comment: Duh! Nice catch HansUp Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I spent way too much time trying to find a way to get `TOP` to accept a parameter.  No luck!  Just curious ... why not a temporary `QueryDef`? `Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, sqlstr)`  After `qdf` is closed, it's gone forever, but maybe keeping it isn't needed.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm trying to use "Select Top " & variable & " ....". That is the entire reason I'm trying to do this in VBA rather than a straight query through the database. Is that not going to be possible? My application is for a skip lot inspection. I'm using top x based on the inspection requirements for the product - some things I'd like to inspect every 4, 9, or 15 lots. By selecting the most recent x lots I can see whether or not the next lot will need to be inspected

Comment: MaryLou, see the changes I just made to the VBA code. You can use a regular expression to change the SQL text in the named query to update TOP n.

Comment: HansUp, good point on the temp QueryDef, I didn't think of that

Comment: I'm not familiar with the RegEx term but I will give it a try! Thank you